# h5py: Store list of list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, hdf5, h5py

Given a list of list of strings, such as:

```
test_array = [ ['a1','a2'], ['b1'], ['c1','c2','c3','c4'] ]
```

I'd like to store it using h5py such that:

```
f['test_dataset'][0] = ['a1','a2']
f['test_dataset'][0][0] = 'a1'
etc.
```

Following the advice in the thread
*[H5py store list of list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873311/h5py-store-list-of-list-of-strings)*, I tried the following:

```
import h5py
test_array = [ ['a1','a2'], ['b1'], ['c1','c2','c3','c4'] ]
with h5py.File('test.h5','w') as f:
    string_dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str)
    f.create_dataset('test_dataset',data=test_array,dtype=string_dt)
```

However this results in each of the nested lists being stored as strings, i.e.:

```
f['test_dataset'][0] = "['a1', 'a2']"
f['test_dataset'][0][0] = '['
```

If this isn't possible using h5py, or any other hdf5-based library, I'd be happy to hear any suggestions of other possible formats/libraries that I could use to store my data.

My data consists of multidimensional numpy integer arrays and nested lists of strings as in the example above, with around >100M rows and ~8 columns.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered storing a flattened version of the list of lists: `x = [ 'a1','a2', 'b1', 'c1','c2','c3','c4' ]`. If you then also store the indices `idx = [2,3]` (where `x` is to be split), then you can regenerate a list of arrays using `np.split(x, idx)`.

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps you could store both `x` and "group numbers" `y = [0,0,1,2,2,2,2]`, which indicate which list the values in `x` are supposed to belong to.

Comment: I was also considering this, however that makes adding new items to existing rows a bit more fiddly. I was also considering just keeping it like this, with the rows stored as strings, and just using eval() on them to convert back to strings when needed, but that comes with some other problems of its own. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38465587) to the [question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37873311) has a link to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14639496), the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639496/python-numpy-array-of-arbitrary-length-strings#answers-header) of which seem like they might help you. (basically they say to use `dtype=object`, and point out that it'll make things slower.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @3D1T0R, however when they say 'variable length strings' in that context, I believe they mean that it's just one list of strings each with a different length, i.e. ['one','twenty','one hundred']. I would like to do this, too, but in my case the problem is storing a multidimensional version of such an array.

Comment: @DanielCrane: It should allow storing any object, including strings, lists or anything else.

Comment: `h5py` does not store general `numpy` object dtype arrays.  HDF5 variable length strings map on to `numpy` object arrays.  As shown then flattened arrays of strings or string objects can be saved, but not nested lists.  That is, `h5py` does not save Python lists.

Answer (score 1):

In [Saving with h5py arrays of different sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214482/saving-with-h5py-arrays-of-different-sizes)

I suggest saving a list of variable length arrays as multiple datasets.

```
In [19]: f = h5py.File('test.h5','w')
In [20]: g = f.create_group('test_array')
In [21]: test_array = [ ['a1','a2'], ['b1'], ['c1','c2','c3','c4'] ]
In [22]: string_dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str)
In [23]: for i,v in enumerate(test_array):
    ...:     g.create_dataset(str(i), data=np.array(v,'S4'), dtype=string_dt)
    ...:     
In [24]: for k in g.keys():
    ...:     print(k,g[k][:])
    ...:     
0 ['a1' 'a2']
1 ['b1']
2 ['c1' 'c2' 'c3' 'c4']
```

For many small sublists this could be messy, though I'm not sure it's in efficient.

'flattening' with a list join might work

```
In [27]: list1 =[', '.join(x) for x in test_array]
In [28]: list1
Out[28]: ['a1, a2', 'b1', 'c1, c2, c3, c4']
In [30]: '\n'.join(list1)
Out[30]: 'a1, a2\nb1\nc1, c2, c3, c4'
```

The nested list can be recreated with a few `split`.

Another thought - pickle to a string and save that.

---

From the `h5py` intro

```
An HDF5 file is a container for two kinds of objects: datasets, which
are array-like collections of data, and groups, which are folder-like
containers that hold datasets and other groups. The most fundamental
thing to remember when using h5py is:

Groups work like dictionaries, and datasets work like NumPy arrays
```

---

`pickle` doesn't work

```
In [32]: import pickle
In [33]: pickle.dumps(test_array)
Out[33]: b'\x80\x03]q\x00(]q\x01(X\x02\x00\x00\x00a1q\x02X\x02\x00\x00\x00a2q\x03e]q\x04X\x02\x00\x00\x00b1q\x05a]q\x06(X\x02\x00\x00\x00c1q\x07X\x02\x00\x00\x00c2q\x08X\x02\x00\x00\x00c3q\tX\x02\x00\x00\x00c4q\nee.'
In [34]: f.create_dataset('pickled', data=pickle.dumps(test_array), dtype=string
    ...: _dt)
....
ValueError: VLEN strings do not support embedded NULLs
```

### json

```
In [35]: import json
In [36]: json.dumps(test_array)
Out[36]: '[["a1", "a2"], ["b1"], ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"]]'
In [37]: f.create_dataset('pickled', data=json.dumps(test_array), dtype=string_d
    ...: t)
Out[37]: <HDF5 dataset "pickled": shape (), type "|O">
In [43]: json.loads(f['pickled'].value)
Out[43]: [['a1', 'a2'], ['b1'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']]
```

Comment: Ah yes, I saw this thread too when I was searching last week. The problem is that this would result in potentially tens or hundreds of millions of datasets, and I'm not sure if that'd affect performance or file size (maybe some overheads?) or not.

Comment: how about `join` to collect the strings into larger string units?  The basic problem is that `HDF5` was developed primarily for multidimensional numeric data, not general lists of list of various items.

Comment: The method I'm currently using does a similar kind of flattening, with each of the nested lists becoming a string, i.e. "['a1','a2']", which can then be converted into an actual list by just using list1 = eval("['a1','a2']"). Storing it like this isn't the end of the world, I just worry about the code readability in the future, and thought it'd be more intuitive if it was possible to store as a real array rather than flattening or stringifying everything. :) Pickling might indeed end up being the best option, I'll look into that a bit more now, thanks for the comment.

Comment: `json` looks more promising than `pickle`.

Answer (score 0):

**ugly workaround**

```
hf.create_dataset('test', data=repr(test_array))
```