# Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent

Tags: numpy, hdf5, h5py

Well, it seems like a couple of similar questions were asked here in stack overflow, but none of them seem like answered correctly or properly, nor they described the exact examples.

I have a problem with saving array or list into hdf5 ...

I have a several files contains list of (n, 35) dimensions, where n may be different in each file. Each of them can be saved in hdf5 with code below.

```
hdf = hf.create_dataset(fname, data=d)
```

However, if I want to merge them to make in 3d the error occurs as below.

> Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent

I have no idea why it turns to dtype object, since what I have done is only this

```
all_data = list()
for fname in file_list:
    d = np.load(fname)
    all_data.append(d)
hdf = hf.create_dataset('all_data', data=all_data)
```

How can I save such data?
I tried a couple of tests, and it seems like all_data turns to dtype with 'object' when I change them with

```
all_data = np.array(all_data)
```

Which looks it has the similar problem with saving hdf5.

Again, how can I save such data in hdf5?

Comment: Since the `d` vary in shape, `numpy` can't make a 3d array from them.  It has to make a 1d object dtype array instead.  `h5py` can't save that (it only saves arrays, not lists or other python objects).  You'll have settle for the original format, one array per `dataset`.

Comment: Similar issue in your neighboring SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53358695/how-to-create-a-2d-numpy-ndarray-using-two-list-comprehensions

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/46422242/3327666 (some details on why you can store only simple arrays in a HDF5 file).

Answer (score 9):

I was running into a similar issue with `h5py`, and changing the type of the NumPy array using `array.astype` worked for me (I believe this changes the type from `dtype('O')` to the data type you specify).  Please see the code snippet below:

```
import numpy as np

print(X.dtype) 
--> dtype('O')

print(X.astype(np.float64).dtype)
--> dtype('float64')
```

When I ran `h5.create_dataset` with this data type conversion, I was able to successfully create a h5 dataset.  Hope this helps!

ONE ADDITIONAL UPDATE: I believe the NumPy object type `'O'` is created when the NumPy array itself has mixed element types (e.g. `np.int8` and `np.float32`).

Answer (score 1):

`dtype('O')` stands for object. In my case I had a list of lists where the lengths were different and got the same error. If you convert it to a numpy array numpy warns `Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences`. h5 files can't handle this type of data for more info see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46400375/how-to-save-h5py-arrays-with-different-sizes)

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when I use:

```
   with h5py.File(peakfilename, 'w') as pfile:  # saves the data
        pfile['peakY'] = np.array(X)
        pfile['peakX'] = np.array(Y)
```

However when I used `dtype` when saving the arrays... the problem went away... I guess h5py is not able to create datasets from undefined data types.

```
   with h5py.File(peakfilename, 'w') as pfile:  # saves the data
        pfile['peakY'] = np.array(X, dtype=np.float32)
        pfile['peakX'] = np.array(Y, dtype=np.float32)
```

Comment: It depends on the object type of `X` and `Y` and the array's dtype created by `np.array()`. What do you get when you enter `type(X)` and `type(np.array(X))`? (and the same for `Y`)

Comment: X and Y both are python lists. I don't have the data but I will try to regenerate the lists. Also the list elements could be of different lengths.