# How to create a 2d numpy ndarray using two list comprehensions

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to create a 2D numpy ndarray using the following code:

```
temp = np.array([[np.mean(w2v[word]) for word in docs if word in w2v] for docs in X[:5]])
```

temp has a shape of (5,) instead of expected (5,x).

Also temps's data structure is like: array([list([.....],...)])

It seems that the inner list is not converted to ndarray.

Comment: Most likely the inner lists differ in length.  It can make a 2d array from that, so it just makes a 1d containing their pointers.  In effect an array equivalent of the original list.

Answer (score 1):

Your missing `np.array` in there, it should be:

```
temp = np.array([np.array([np.mean(w2v[word]) for word in docs if word in w2v] for docs in X[:5])])
```

Running example:

```
bob
Out[70]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

tmp = np.array([np.array([x for x in Y]) for Y in bob])

tmp
Out[72]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: Note that as @hpaulj  commented, np can't really handle not squared 2d matrices, in which case you will have an array of np arrays.