# Writing Python list as HDF5 file using h5py module

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, h5py

I have created a Python list containing random values created using TensorFlow 2.0 which I then want to save as HDF5 file using "h5py" module in Python.

The code I am using is as follows-

```
# list to hold values-
wts_extracted = []

wts_extracted.append(tf.cast(tf.random.normal(shape = (4, 4), mean = 0, stddev = 1), dtype=tf.float32))
wts_extracted.append(tf.cast(tf.random.normal(shape = (4,), mean = 0, stddev = 1), dtype=tf.float32))
wts_extracted.append(tf.cast(tf.random.normal(shape = (4, 3), mean = 0, stddev = 1), dtype=tf.float32))
wts_extracted.append(tf.cast(tf.random.normal(shape = (3, ), mean = 0, stddev = 1), dtype=tf.float32))
wts_extracted.append(tf.cast(tf.random.normal(shape = (3, 1), mean = 0, stddev = 1), dtype=tf.float32))
wts_extracted.append(tf.cast(tf.random.normal(shape = (1, ), mean = 0, stddev = 1), dtype=tf.float32))

# Convert Python list to numpy array-
n = np.array(wts_extracted)

n.shape
# (6,)

type(n)
# numpy.ndarray

# Save manually created weights as '.h5' file-
with h5py.File("manually_created_weights.h5", "w") as f:
    dset = f.create_dataset("default", data = n)
```

The error message I get is:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 with h5py.File("manually_created_weights.h5", "w") as f:
>   ----> 2         dset = f.create_dataset("default", data = n)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py in
>   create_dataset(self, name, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)
>       134 
>       135         with phil:
>   --> 136             dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(self, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)
>       137             dset = dataset.Dataset(dsid)
>       138             if name is not None:
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py in
>   make_new_dset(parent, shape, dtype, data, chunks, compression,
>   shuffle, fletcher32, maxshape, compression_opts, fillvalue,
>   scaleoffset, track_times, external, track_order, dcpl)
>       116         else:
>       117             dtype = numpy.dtype(dtype)
>   --> 118         tid = h5t.py_create(dtype, logical=1)
>       119 
>       120     # Legacy
>
> h5py/h5t.pyx in h5py.h5t.py_create()
>
> h5py/h5t.pyx in h5py.h5t.py_create()
>
> h5py/h5t.pyx in h5py.h5t.py_create()
>
> TypeError: Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent

I read that in order to use "h5py" module, you should convert Pythonic objects to numpy arrays, which I did. What's going wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT:

"h5py" cannot handle different shapes/dimensions, hence, I have the following code:

```
# Save the different shape arrays as separate datasets:

# Python dict-
wts_extracted_dict = {}

l = 0

while l < len(wts_extracted):
    wts_extracted_dict['layer-{0}'.format(l)] = wts_extracted[l]
    l += 1


# Create '.h5' file on HDD-
f = h5py.File("manual_weights.h5", "w")

# Create a group-
grp = f.create_group("alist")

for k, v in wts_extracted_dict.items():
    grp.create_dataset(k, data=v)

grp
# <HDF5 group "/alist" (6 members)>

f.close()
```

However, when I try to read the saved file and access the groups as follows:

```
f = h5py.File("manual_weights.h5", "r")

f.keys()
# <KeysViewHDF5 ['alist']>

f['alist']
# <HDF5 group "/alist" (6 members)>

type(f['alist'])
# h5py._hl.group.Group
```

How do I access the group?

Comment: Check the contents and the dtype of the arrays, the Object dtype is used when a NumPy array can only store references to Python objects (an ndarray of lists, or ndarray of strings, etc.).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving with h5py arrays of different sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214482/saving-with-h5py-arrays-of-different-sizes)

Comment: The list arrays differ in size.  `h5py` can't save that kind of array.

Comment: Look at the `keys` of the group just as you did with the file.  `groups` are like dictionaries, and may be nested, but ultimately will contain datasets.  `groups` should be adequately described in the the `h5py` docs.

Comment: The group `['alist']` has 6 members (datasets created in your `for k, v` loop. You get the dataset names the same way you got group names. Reference the group object (instead of the file object), like this `f['alist'].keys()`. Once you have the dataset names, access them like this: `f['alist']['dataset_name']`or `f['alist/dataset_name']`.